# Generate random vector relative to current vector within a certain degree in 3D space

Tags: vector, quaternion

I'm creating a simple ray tracer and I think this would be the best place to ask. I've created my own engine in Go, and I've gotten pretty far. I am now implementing diffuse surfaces, so I'll need to generate a random direction to send scattered rays to fake diffuse.

I've looked at the other questions on here, and I found that was similar to my question, but it was for 2D space, and not 3D.

Let's say I have a direction `a`, and I want to generate a new direction that is random, and within 45 degrees of direction `a`. Since I'm working in 3D space, I can't simply find the perpendicular angle and lerp between them, so I'll need to do something different. For example, this is what I'd do in 2D:

```
dir = Vector2(1, 1).Normal()

perpDir = dir.Perp() // gets the perpendicular direction of `dir`

randDir = dir.Lerp(perpDir, rand() - 0.5) // rand is [0, 1)
```

I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to math, so this needs to be pretty dumbed down for me to understand. Is there any simple way to find a random direction based on a current direction with a maximum rotation of a set maximum rotation like 90 degrees?

Comment: Generate a random 3d vector.  Normalize and dot product to ensure it's not perpendicular.  Then cross product to get the perpendicular axis.   Then random rotation value with in your selected range on your direction vector using axis.  Done.

Comment: For a fast random vector on a hemisphere defined by the normal of the surface, you generate random vector and multiply it by the sign of dot product between normal and random vector.

Comment: @Ocelot and ErnieDingo: these look like Answers, not comments. Post them below so we can vote on them and give you some rep for sharing! :)

Comment: @DMGregory my comment does not really answer the question, it's just a tip.